# Is there a button or keyboard shortcut to “Find Next In Project” in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

In Xcode, you can use **Find** → **Find Next** or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to find the next result matching the current search, *but only in the current document.* Is there a similar command that will find the next search result in a project-wide search? This would be similar to how **Navigate** → **Jump to Next Issue** (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>) works, except for Find results instead of compiler issues. It should jump to the text itself in the editor, not the listing of the find result in the sidebar.

Comment: Click the magnifying glass to do project-wide search.

Comment: Clarified the question. I’m looking for a shortcut or button to select the text of the next result in the code editor, without having to jump focus back and forth between the editor and the Find sidebar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xcode 8 has this, use ctrl-cmd-G.

Comment: Perfect! This is the correct answer. The corresponding menu command is *Find* → *Find Next in Workspace*

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Xcode Menu --> Preferences --> Key Binding -->Find Menu`, then you can see what are all options available and you can cofigure those.

If you can't see the desired option here, then you can't.

[image]

Comment: Accepted because you answered my question (“Can you…” “No.”). I still wish there were some way to do it. I will probably file a radar.

Comment: Update: [santeri's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39770611/255489) is the correct one.